# Use of conservation of energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

[image]

> A ball starts rolling down a slope as shown in the figure below. All
>   units shown are in meters. The floor has very little friction. Which
>   of the following is true after a long time?

options

A. The ball will come to rest at P

B. The ball will come to rest at Q

C. The ball will come to rest at R

D. The ball will continue to be in motion at point S

My approach was to break down the problem in two parts and use conservation of energy. First part would be from peak to point P, then point P to small peak. If the energy stored in the ball is greater than the energy reuired to climb the samll peak it will pass. So, from peak to point P , 1/2*m*v^2 = mgh or V^2=20 ( approax g= 10 taken). But I am unable to proceed farther. What should be the eqaution for next part ( point P to small peak)?

Comment: Hi Ritwik and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Let's assume that the ball's path is not obstructed (see @NarcosisGF's answer).*

You can ignore the peak because it is lower than the starting height.

At start, some amount of potential energy is stored. It is all converted into kinetic energy at P.

Then the ball starts to rise. It can rise just as high as it started. Since the peak clearly is lower than the starting height, there will be no trouble overcoming the peak.

---

That being said, this drawing is severely flawed. @NarcosisGF points out one issue, namely that the vertical part of the small peak will alter its path to perfectly vertical. Thus it will never *pass* the peak but just drop straight vertically back down into the valley again.

Secondly, even if this is assumed a drawing mistake and we assume that it should be a sloped path, the ball will never be able to reach point Q as it will fly over the peak and land far away.

Thirdly, when landing it will bounce. If not, then energy is sucked out of it by the soft ground and you can't be sure of the speed (since the kinetic energy is then altered). The arrow at S is thus not a good represention of the ball's speed.

Comment: Hello, sorry for such a late reply, But I was new to stack exchange and I also lost my password to my registered mail id. Can you please tell me 
what is the issue with vertical part. I mean even if  its there why can't the ball pass in vertically and land on the other side of the valley?

Comment: Hi @RitwickBhattacharyya, no problem. Which part are you asking about?

Comment: @NarcosisGF points out one issue, namely that the vertical part of the small peak will alter its path to perfectly vertical. Thus it will never pass the peak but just drop straight vertically back down into the valley again. This thing I am not able to understand. Why can't it drop on the other side even if there's a veritcal slope

Comment: @RitwickBhattacharyya Because, to pass the slope it must move not only vertically but also horizontally. The vertical left side of the peak turns the motion to become only vertical. Thus it will not move horizontally and can't get any further rightwards.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, between the points $P$ and $Q$ there is a part of the path that is completely vertical. At that point, the velocity will have vertical orientation and there is no reason by which it acquires a horizontal speed that makes it reach $Q$. The ball will oscillate around $P$ until it finishes its movement at that point due to the friction.

Comment: Ha, that is a good point  Don't you think that's a drawing mistake, though?

Comment: Apparently, the problem gives you the radius of a quarter of a circumference between P and Q (that of $ 0.14 $). If so, the "small friction" condition would allow you to use the reasoning I followed.